# How can I create feathered edges on a circle?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, transparency

I have a circle mesh that I'd like to be opaque for most of its surface, but slowly fade to transparency at the edges.
My current node setup is this:
[image: Node setup]

But my result is a mostly transparent circle that is more transparent around the edges:
[image: Preview result]

Any small adjustment to the "Blend" setting causes the preview sphere to become either pitch black or invisible. Even if I did find the correct setting, I don't think it'd work properly because I'd like it to be only the edges that fade, not the entire circle.
The end result I'd like is closer to this (badly photoshopped):
[image: What I want my circle to look like]
Any help you can give is very much appreciated!

Comment: Try to use a gradient texture (quadratic sphere) completed by a color ramp (ease).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a **RGB Curve** or a **Color Ramp** node to control the transition :

[image: with rgb curve]

[image: with color ramp]

Comment: I want to texture this effect so that only some areas have the effect where would I place the texture? If I can't figure it out I'll ask it as an actual question.